Determining bonding characteristics of a structure from PDOS
Recently, I have been working with PDOS. I can read and understand PDOS to some extent, but I am not an expert in it. These are some of the graphs I have been working on. Can someone explain how to identify bonding states (such as hybridization states of the structure, distinguishing eg and t2g states from ligand/crystal field theory) from the PDOS? (Comparing your interpretations with mine will help me ensure I am on the right track). I have attached the graphs below.
Thank you.


